# Accessing Custom Settings via Apex VF class

Tags: apex, customsetting

I am trying to access custom settings via Apex, but it refuses to work properly.

I've got the following two examples:

```
public class PO_PartnerTeam_OppCustomController  {
   public Integration_Partner_Scoring__c test = new Integration_Partner_Scoring__c.getInstance('Test');
}
```

The below is anonymous apex::

```
Integration_Partner_Scoring__c test = [SELECT Id, Name FROM 
Integration_Partner_Scoring__c];
System.debug('test output :: ' + test);

Integration_Partner_Scoring__c test2 =  Integration_Partner_Scoring__c.getAll().values();
System.debug('test2 output :: ' + test2);

Integration_Partner_Scoring__c test3 =  Integration_Partner_Scoring__c.getInstance();
System.debug('test3 output :: ' + test3);
```

The anonymous Apex works fine, and returns my custom settings just fine. This lets me confirm the custom setting is indeed created, and available. But the class won't, and I cannot figure out why. I will note, I can save `Integration_Partner_Scoring__c test = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Integration_Partner_Scoring__c];` just fine in the class(and if I log that to console it gives the expected results), but I am wondering why I cannot get it using the `getInstance`.

I can compile it without `.getInstance()` and it works fine just creating a new copy of `Integration_Partner_Scoring__c`, but it refuses to work with `.getInstance()`. It just gives me the error `Invalid type: Integration_Partner_Scoring__c.getInstance`.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the new keyword. The following should work. [Refer documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm).

```
public class PO_PartnerTeam_OppCustomController  {
   public Integration_Partner_Scoring__c test =Integration_Partner_Scoring__c.getInstance('Test');
}
```

Comment: Well, I feel silly. But I'm also glad it didn't end up being something big. I'll read the documentation and make a mental note of this. Thanks! Appreciate it :)

Comment: @Genko Can you mark this as the answer? Otherwise, the community will keep bumping this question to top.

Comment: I am going to in a bit. I tried but stackexchange threw a 'You cannot mark an answer for 6 minutes' message. Just waiting on that.